# How to apply sed command to the matched pattern text and replace in file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have text in my file and there are other blocks matching with:
`build.gradle`:

```
... 
staging {
             buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOUR_NAME', '"appName"'
             // buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://abcd.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://example.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'MEDIA_HOST', '"https://example.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'APPHOSTURL', '"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details/"'
             applicationId = "com.example.staging" 
}
 
...
```

My objective is to find the next three lines to include the 'HOST' line (ignoring the commented ones) corresponding to the pattern:

> staging {

I got it using:

```
sed -n "/staging {/{n;N;N;p;}" build.gradle
```

Output:

```
             buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOUR_NAME', '"appName"'
             // buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://abcd.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://example.com"'
```

Further, I need to apply the pattern match from this output and replace the text in file then.

Another command that I got it using was:

```
sed -n "/staging {/{n;N;N;p;}" build.gradle | sed "/^\s\+\/\//! s/'HOST', .*$/'HOST', '\"https:\/\/test.com\"'/"
```

Output:

```
             buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOUR_NAME', '"appName"'
             // buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://abcd.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://test.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'MEDIA_HOST', '"https://example.com"'
```

Everything is alright so far, but my problem is I don't know how to replace the changes in the existing file.

I need the final output (which should be replaced in the existing file) as:

```
... 

staging {
             buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOUR_NAME', '"appName"'
             // buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://abcd.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://test.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'MEDIA_HOST', '"https://example.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'APPHOSTURL', '"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details/"'
             applicationId = "com.example.staging" 
}

...
```

But `sed -i` is not working after feeding the input from pipe output.

Kindly guide me the way with sed or awk or any other.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Special thanks for showing your efforts in form of code. Could you please post sample of input and expected output more clearly in your question and let us know then, for better understanding of question.

Comment: Isn't there any sensible Gradle-specific way to do this modification into the build file?

Comment: I voted to **reopen**. Details, clarity and efforts already exist in this question, with a minimum and reproducible test case. The quest is how to modify a file combining two existing sed commands (provided into the question) or by any other awk, sed, bash way.

Comment: I also vote to reopen because it is unclear what 'details or clarity' is/are missing. How can someone improve this question without knowing what 'details or clarity' is/are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to combine two `sed` commands for this task, without folding any lines.

```
sed "/^staging {$/,/^}$/{
        s/\(^\s*b.*'HOST', '\"\).*\(\"'\)/\1https:\/\/test.com\2/
    }" file
```

The first range `/^staging {$/,/^}$/` defines the area where the following substitution `{s/...}` can happen. Note that if you have many `{}` blocks , the substitution will be tested only inside `staging{ }` blocks.

You could add `-i` for inplace editing after you are done with testing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly. 
Had to modify the regex a little:
sed "/^\s\+staging {$/,/^\s\+}$/{ /^\s\+\/\//! s/'HOST', .*$/'HOST', '\"test.com\"'/}" build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

consider the following awk file (`changeBuild.awk`):

```
# count { and } characters
{ t=$0; brackets+=gsub(/{/,"",t)-gsub(/}/,"",t); }
# find where we need a change
$0~where1{ w1=brackets;}
$0~where2{ w2=brackets;}
# change it
$0~changefrom && brackets<=w1 && $0~where2 { gsub(changefrom, changeto, $0) }
# print it
{ print $0;
  if (brackets<w1){ w1=0 };
  if (brackets<w2){ w2=0 };
}
```

Then this line will change your build.gradle:

```
gawk -v where1=staging -v where2=\'HOST -v changefrom=example.com -v changeto=test.com -f changeBuild.awk build.gradle
```

- It will count the number of `{` and `}` to know if you are in the correct block.
- `where1` and `where2` determine where info needs to be changed.
- `changefrom` and `changeto` determine what to change.

Because this is a pretty simple script, it might need adaptation if more `whereX` values are needed, but that should be pretty simple to add.

The counting in `w2` is not needed (here), but i used a more complex example with more levels of '{' and '}'.

TODO:

- Check for commented lines, which should not be changed.

.

```
staging {
             buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOUR_NAME', '"appName"'
             // buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://abcd.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://test.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'MEDIA_HOST', '"https://example.com"'
             buildConfigField 'String', 'APPHOSTURL', '"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details/"'
             applicationId = "com.example.staging"
}
```

EDIT (found a bug):

- `$0~changefrom && brackets>=w1 && $0~where2` was changed to `$0~changefrom && brackets<=w1 && $0~where2`. Because the number of brackets are larger for sub-blocks.
- `-v where2=HOST` was change to `-v where2=\'HOST`. The text "MEDIA_HOST" also matched the text HOST. This adds the initial `'` to the match.

Comment: It worked but also changed the HOST in other blocks for cases where the match was found.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the file format

versionName 0.0.3

Expected: versionName 0.0.4

```bash
sed -ie 's/versionName .*/versionName 0.0.4/' "filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the file format

`versionName 0.0.3`

Expected: `versionName 0.0.4`

Use command:
`sed -ie 's/versionName .*/versionName 0.0.4/' "filename"`